# Run parallel job and transmit its output continuously in PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script (running via WinRM) thatcontinuously outputs some info to the caller. At some point, it runs an executable (lasting a few minutes):

```
Write-Output "Starting..."
cmd /c """$exePath"""
Write-Output "Finished"
```

I would like in parallel to the exe to do another job which also continuously outputs some info to the script caller:

```
While (exe not finished) {
    Write-Output "Some info"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

The caller should receive each line of

```
Starting
Some info
Some info
Some info
Finished
```

as soon as they are executed, because it has to show them on a GUI continuously.

How can I achieve that? I can't continuously call `Receive-Job` because the script is busy with the executable.

Comment: Simplest solution for you would be to use Jobs or Runspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {start-sleep 20 # Your scriptblock here}
while ($job.state -eq 'running'){
    Write-Output "Job still running"
    Start-Sleep 1
}
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! I was not thinking on using the job for the executable itself, though that now seems obvious.